# How to use a txt file to fill a variable in a batch script. Then loop through to use all the names in the text file as variables until exhausted

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code that I use to pull the users names into a text file. I want to use the file as inputs. I can't seem to grasp how to do this.

The tools in this example come from: https://ericzimmerman.github.io/#!index.md,
https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/EricZimmermanTools/JLECmd.zip, and
https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/EricZimmermanTools/ShellBagsExplorer.zip

The actual code that I have so far. The file is run like this, `users.bat InputDrive OutputDrive Systemname "Username from text file"`.

```
@echo off
title Users.bat %1 %2 %3 %4  
cls
echo This batch file will dump shellbags.
rem start cmd.exe /A /k "CD /D %1:\Users"  
CD /D %1:\Users 
for /d %%D in (*) do echo %%~nxD >> %2:/Users.txt 
cd /D C:\CommandPost\Kit-Analysis
C:\Test-Kit\ShellBagsExplorer\SBECmd.exe -d "%1:\Users\%4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows" --csv "%2:\Results-Analysis\%3\Users\%4\ShellBags"
C:\Test-Kit\JLECmd\JLECmd.exe -d "%1:\Users\%4\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent" --csv "%2:\Results-Analysis\%3\Users\%4\JumpList" --html "%2:\Results-Analysis\%3\Users\%4\JumpList-Html"
echo Finished
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really mean to say is you want to use the output from the `FOR /D` command as a variable to the two executable programs you want to run.

```
@echo off
title Users.bat %1 %2 %3  
cls
echo This batch file will dump shellbags. 
CD /D %1:\Users 
for /d %%D in (*) do (
    pushd C:\CommandPost\Kit-Analysis
    C:\Test-Kit\ShellBagsExplorer\SBECmd.exe -d "%1:\Users\%%D\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows" --csv "%2:\Results-Analysis\%3\Users\%%D\ShellBags"
    C:\Test-Kit\JLECmd\JLECmd.exe -d "%1:\Users\%%D\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent" --csv "%2:\Results-Analysis\%3\Users\%%D\JumpList" --html "%2:\Results-Analysis\%3\Users\%%D\JumpList-Html"
    popd
)
echo Finished
```

Comment: that is correct. I want the output to be used where you have %%D now. I will try that and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Squashman can you smack me and help me with another post I have. I am totally missing what I am being told. I understood your answer if you are willing to help that would be greatly appreciated.